# R: Error making time series stationary using diff()

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a dataset with monthly data starting from the 1st of every month during a period of time.

Here's head() of my Date column:

```
> class(gas_data$Date)
[1] "Date"

> head(gas_data$Date)
[1] "2010-10-01" "2010-11-01" "2010-12-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-02-01" "2011-03-01"
```

Trying to make the time series stationary, I'm using diff() from the base package:

```
> gas_data_diff <- diff(gas_data, differences = 1, lag = 12)

> head(gas_data_diff)
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows

> names(gas_data_diff)
character(0)

> gas_data_diff %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Price.Gas)) +
+   geom_line(color="darkorchid4")


Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Price.Gas' not found
```

As you can see I get an error, and when trying to visualize the data with head() or look for the feature names I get an unexpected output.

**Why am I getting this error and how could I fix it?**

Here's head() of my original data

```
> head(gas_data)
        Date Per.Change Domestic.Production.from.UKCS Import Per.GDP.Growth Average.Temperature Price.Electricity Price.Gas
1 2010-10-01      2.08                          3.54   5.40            0.2               10.44             43.50     46.00
2 2010-11-01     -3.04                          3.46   6.74           -0.1                5.52             46.40     49.66
3 2010-12-01      0.31                          3.54   9.00           -0.9                0.63             58.03     62.26
4 2011-01-01      2.65                          3.59   7.58            0.6                4.05             48.43     55.98
5 2011-02-01      1.52                          3.20   5.68            0.4                6.29             46.47     53.74
6 2011-03-01     -1.38                          3.40   5.93            0.5                6.59             51.41     60.39
```

This is how the non-stationary plot of the original data looks like for gas prices for instances
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

As per help from `diff`, the argument `x` must be

> `x : a numeric vector or matrix containing the values to be differenced.`

As in your case, `diff` returns an eplty data.frame if `x` is a dataframe.

---

### Best approach IMO

I don't see much of point in using the date column in `diff`. So. I am likely to follow the following approach.

```
rownames(df) <- df$Date                                                                      
diff(as.matrix(df[, - 1]), lag = 1)  

# converr to a matrix and apply diff
diff_mat <- diff(as.matrix(df[, - 1]), lag = 1)     

# convert back to dataframe and set the Date column                                                 
diff_df <- as.data.frame(diff_mat) 
diff_df$Date <- diff_df$Date

# now plot function should work
```

---

### Using the data given to address the comments.

Convert the Date vector to numeric and then convert to matrix in diff

```
df$Date <- as.numeric(df$Date)
diff(as.matrix(df), 1, 2)                                                                    
#      Date Per.Change Domestic.Production.from.UKCS Import Per.GDP.Growth
# [1,]   -1       8.47                          0.16   0.92           -0.5
# [2,]    1      -1.01                         -0.03  -3.68            2.3
# [3,]    0      -3.47                         -0.44  -0.48           -1.7
# [4,]   -3      -1.77                          0.59   2.15            0.3
#      Average.Temperature Price.Electricity Price.Gas
# [1,]                0.03              8.73      8.94
# [2,]                8.31            -21.23    -18.88
# [3,]               -1.18              7.64      4.04
# [4,]               -1.94              6.90      8.89
```

### Creating the Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Date Per.Change Domestic.Production.from.UKCS Import Per.GDP.Growth Average.Temperature Price.Electricity Price.Gas
2010-10-01      2.08                          3.54   5.40            0.2               10.44             43.50     46.00
2010-11-01     -3.04                          3.46   6.74           -0.1                5.52             46.40     49.66
2010-12-01      0.31                          3.54   9.00           -0.9                0.63             58.03     62.26
2011-01-01      2.65                          3.59   7.58            0.6                4.05             48.43     55.98
2011-02-01      1.52                          3.20   5.68            0.4                6.29             46.47     53.74
2011-03-01     -1.38                          3.40   5.93            0.5                6.59             51.41     60.39", 
header = T, sep ="")

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

Comment: But there's a date in it... Shouldn't the date be of type date? When converted to a numeric type it looks like a random number...

Comment: All values are in type numeric and nothing is plotted... the plot is blank...

Comment: Your option is to `gas_data$Date <- as.numeric(gas_data$Date)`, and then `gas_data <- as.matrix(gas_data)`.

Comment: If you don't do the first step then the second step will create a matrix of character type.

Comment: The conversion of the date to a numeric type is not a problem. I'm still not getting output on my plot. When looking at the environment gas_fata_diff has 118 obs. of 0 variables. Where are the variables going? The problem is around it not finding my features for some reason...

Comment: OK There's progress!! diff() is working now and I can see the date converted into the number of days in a month (28/30/31) - when using lag=1. However, I'm still getting an error when plotting. **Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector**

Comment: `lag = 1` works for the data given in your question. Very likely you have a different problem now.

Comment: Could you plot it as well just to double-check if you'd also get this error? I already accepted your question and will post another one with this additional issue...

Comment: To use ggplot2 you have to convert it back to a data.frame. I also addes a section based on what I think you are trying to do.